# jinja2 templates not getting read

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I tried running a simple python programme to output employee details using flask and jinja2. while running the programme, i m getting the above error shown in the image.

[image]

The jinja2 templates are not getting read.
I m sure that the codes are correct as i have ran it without any issues earlier on ubuntu. Now i was trying it on my windows. Python version-3.6.6, jinja2 version-2.10
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be helpful tu see your code

Comment: Could you please help us with your code ?